# how to pull data from attribute within element

Tags: xpath, scrapy

In my attempts at writing a spider with scrapy, Im trying to extract data from within an element just like you would for a href
eg `<tr><td><a href = "www.somelink.com">` would be `hxs.select('//tr/td/a/@href').extract()`
So what we are doing here is getting the data that is assigned to href

I have a span element that has a class and a data attribute as such
`<span class="classname" data="{...data in here...}">`

but trying the below produces errors in scrapy, where im selecting the data attribute of the span element where the span elements class = classname.

`hxs.select('//div/span[@class="classname"]/@data/').extract()`

Is it even possible to pull data from attributes other than href and if so how do I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you remove the trailing slash after `@data`?

Comment: It may be that the HTML parser doesn't allow the "data" attribute on a span element, and has therefore ignored it at parse time. You could try extracting `//div/span[@class="classname"]/@*` to see what attributes it thinks are there.

Comment: wait on, my fat fingers gave me the wrong answer. It was the extra / Thanks heaps